# Apache Commons VFS get or put files over a port-mapping

Tags: sftp, vfs

I have a question with using commons-vfs2 just like the picture, there is a server between the client and the file server which used to map the file server port from 22 to 10022, how can i use the commons-vfs2 upload or download file from the file server via sftp and ftp protocol?

I tried to use proxy like following code:

```
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setProxyHost(opts, "xxx.6.2.xx");
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setProxyPort(opts, 10022);
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setProxyType(opts, SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.PROXY_HTTP);
```

but it's not work, the picture url is http://ccwuj.img44.wal8.com/img44/507529_20150115150159/143279929037.jpg